# (PHP) User is being forced to RE-LOGIN after trying to do something on an admin page

Tags: php, authentication

I have created an admin panel for a client in PHP, which requires a login. Here is the code at the top of the admin page requiring the user to be logged in:

admin.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require("_lib/session_functions.php");
require("_lib/db.php");
db_connect();


//if the user has not logged in
if(!isLoggedIn())
{
    header('Location: login_form.php');
    die();
}
?>
```

Obviously, the if statement is what catches them and forces them to log in. Here is the code on the resulting login page:

login_form.php

```
<form name="login" action="login.php" method="post">
    Username: <input type="text" name="username" />
    Password: <input type="password" name="password" />
    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

Which posts info to this controller page:

login.php

```
<?php
session_start(); //must call session_start before using any $_SESSION variables
include '_lib/session_functions.php';

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

include '_lib/db.php'; 
db_connect(); // Connect to the DB

$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);

$query = "<grab username, hashed password from DB>;";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if(mysql_num_rows($result) < 1) //no such user exists
{
    header('Location: login_form.php?login=fail');
    die();
}

$userData = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
db_disconnect();
$hash = hash('<myHashingFunction>', $password . $userData['salt']);

if($hash != $userData['password']) //incorrect password
{
    header('Location: login_form.php?login=fail');
    die();
}
else
{
    validateUser(); //sets the session data for this user
}

header('Location: admin.php');

?>
```

and the session functions page that provides login functions contains this:

session_functions.php

```
<?php
function validateUser()
{
    session_regenerate_id (); //this is a security measure
    $_SESSION['valid'] = 1;
    $_SESSION['userid'] = $username;
}

function isLoggedIn()
{
    if($_SESSION['valid'])
        return true;

    return false;
}

function logout()
{
    $_SESSION = array(); //destroy all of the session variables
    if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
        $params = session_get_cookie_params();
        setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
            $params["path"], $params["domain"],
            $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
        );
    }
    session_destroy();
}
?>
```

I grabbed the sessions_functions.php code of an online tutorial, so it could be suspicious.

Any ideas why the user logs in to the admin panel, tries to do something, is forced to re-login, and THEN is allowed to do stuff like normal in the admin panel?

Comment: What parameters do you set for your session cookie in validateUser()?

Comment: validateUser() is defined in session_functions.php, which is posted above. if that doesn't answer your question, then i don't understand what you're asking

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I would track down (with livehttpheaders etc) if the session id received/sent by browser matches with the one on server after successfull login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remember to clear your browser cookies if the client switches servers :)

Answer (score 0):

Be careful when using session_regenerate_id with redirects. In general. Don't.

Comment: so try getting rid of that line?

Comment: I would definitely recommend you get rid of it and see if it fixes your problem.

Comment: ohhh. you're redirecting after establishing a session. you'll probably lose your session variables. it's a common problem. don't redirect after login. perform a full page fetch and then redirect with a meta tag and/or Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Is it just me, or is your `isLoggedIn` function really insecure? All you do is check for the existence of a session variable, which anyone could fake with a random value. You need to check the actual session ID/hash against a database of validated/logged in users.

Comment: how would someone set a session variable from the outside..?